# Example open source projects built using maven and test with TestNG

Tags: java, testng, mutation-testing

I'm looking at adding TestNG support to http://pitest.org and could do with some real and dirty code to try it out on.

Can anyone suggest some smallish open source projects that are build using maven and use TestNG for unit testing?

For clarity - I am not asking how to configure maven to use TestNG, I am looking for some example projects to use as input to a mutation testing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, Seam and Tapestry both use TestNG. Obviously, TestNG itself uses TestNG.

There is also a lot of activity on the Selenium front, check out the Selenium boards.

Comment: Tapestry or seam looks like they might work for me. I really need unit tests rather than integration tests so Selenium doesn't fit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you only need to add the testng dependency to your pom with scope test and surefire will handle that already...(may be you need to update surefire plugin).

Comment: My question is not how to configure a project for maven and TestNG, my question is can anyone suggest some example projects that use these two technologies together so that I can run a mutation testing tool against them.